# coreplot bar tap not working

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, core-plot, bar-chart

I have downloaded this code from Github : https://github.com/gilthonweapps/CorePlotBarChartExample  .How to get onTap for bar selected ? I am using the following code:

```
#pragma mark - CPTBarPlotDelegate methods
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

     NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index);
}
```

But this is not working (Its not recognizing the Tap).Please Help.
Thanks in Advance and Happy New Year.

Comment: Complete answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121683/how-to-set-plot-delegate-in-coreplot/14122424#14122424  .Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the plot `delegate` to your bar plot delegate object. This is usually the view controller but it does not have to be.

Comment: Thanks Eric Sir but how do I do that? Can you please explain more It would be a great help .Trying to figure it out for more than 10 days now.Thanks again.

Comment: I have changed CPTPlotSpaceDelegate to CPTBarPlotDelegate and I have an issue :::  Assigning to 'id<CPTPlotSpaceDelegate>' from incompatible type 'GraphView *'

Comment: A single class can implement more than one protocol. Make sure both `CPTPlotSpaceDelegate` and `CPTBarPlotDelegate` are listed in the class definition.