# how to set plot delegate in coreplot

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, core-plot, bar-chart

This is a follow up question from this link : [coreplot bar tap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112893/coreplot-bar-tap-not-working)  and the answer is : `Set the plot delegate to your bar plot delegate object.` PLease can anybody tell me how .I am trying to create a simple bar-chart with on tap for 10 days and there is no tutorial which explains the process in simple words. It would be a great help and I would really appreciate it .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your CPTBarPlot delegate. Until it is set, the CPTBarPlot object doesn't know where to send it's delegate method to.

In `GraphView.m`

Look for `plot.dataSource = self` and add the line `plot.delegate = self` (it's in the code where you are creating your `CPTBarPlot *plot`)

Then be sure to add the delegate method implementation to GraphView.m.

That should work, but it's worth pointing out that you should should not really be putting your dataSource and delegate methods in your view. This is a job for the view controller, as the controller mediates between the view and it's model, and directs user interaction. Similarly, your `generateData` method does not belong in the view, the data should be set / sent to the view via the view controller (I guess it's there just for testing purposes, but best to start as you mean to go on...).

Comment: Thanks for the input.Can you please make a tutorial or put a source code link for simple barplot on Github It would be of great help for all the users .I have spent 5 days trying to look for a offline chart and 10 more days to figure out core-plot there are only 3 tutorials online and the explanation is not made on  step by step basis .Your contribution would be of a great help to everyone.Thanks again and Happy New Year.

Comment: I agree - online resources are fairly poor which is surprising given such a rich and useful library. Have you seen the [tutorial on raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1). That looks pretty good and does explicitly show the setting of datasource and delegates. It didn't exist a year ago when I was similarly struggling with corePlot, but looks like a great jumping off point.

Comment: That was one of the tutorial I was talking about but still they are not talking/showing about customizing based on the user. Basically the x/y axis data and horizontal scrolling or how it is going to expand if there are more data on x-axis .Flexible padding and auto adjustment .Nothing has been spoken about all these features and more ,As these are things that matters if user is going to use it as a library in their project .

Comment: Please create a tutorial Sir it would be of great help to all. Currently it would be great if your tutorials focuses on customizations .And Please update the link here in this question once its done.Thanks again Sir. Have a Great Day.